# Python no module named 'requests' even install requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I run my python scrapy project shows the error `no module named 'requests'`

So I type `pip install requests`

and then terminal information:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (1.25.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (2019.11.28)
```

type command `pip list` can see `request 2.22.0`

I type command `python --version` to check the python version:

```
python 2.7.16
```

Finally I run my scrapy project again still see the same error `no module named 'requests'`

I have no idea how to fix the error now, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you python3? if yes you have to install requests by `pip3 install requests`

Comment: As a side note, since support for Python 2.7 has been officially discontinued, you should consider switching to 3.x.

Comment: Hmm... If I type `pip3 install requests` will show the same information. So I have to switch my python version on my mac and install it with `pip3 install requests` and then run my python project, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `python3` and `pip3` and then `pip3 install requests`

if you are on ubuntu `python3` is installed by default

you should first install `pip3` by `apt install python3-pip` and then `pip3 install requests`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like I have pip3 before.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using two different versions of Python, it should explain why you can't use your module.

To install the module on Python 3, try:

```
pip3 install requests
```

And make sure, you are using the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the same interpreter to which you have installed the package using `pip install`. As a best practice to avoid this type of issues when you have multiple versions of python, use pip as a module instead of directly calling pip.

eg:

`python -m pip install requests`

`python3 -m pip install requests`